# What is the difference between a cafe and a diner?

Tags: meaning, differences

I recently ate at an establishment called The Park Cafe and Diner. How could a debate not ensue? What is the difference between a Cafe and Diner? Apparently, this place is both.

I have read various opinions online that discuss the visibility of the kitchen, the presence of counter-seating and such. But nothing authoritative.

Is/was there a commonly understood difference, or have they been relatively interchangeable and perhaps regionally variable?

[image]

Comment: I suppose, a cafe serves light meals, and a diner.. heavy meals.

Comment: Etymologically speaking, ***cafes*** serve *drinks* (originally, *coffee*). ***Diners*** are places where you *eat (dine)*.

Comment: Diners will serve you breakfast/dinner any time of day, unlike cafes.

Comment: This is partly a 'cultural/national' issue. The term 'diner' is rare in the UK, and a café may or may not serve meals all day, which is also the case for pubs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  It's a shame that the only 'real' information here is in your comment.

Comment: This question is POB because it is undoubtedly "regionally variable". OP, provide the definitions of these two words (to avoid GR), and the location specifics (to avoid POB). Also, a courtesy crop of that phone number is in order.

Comment: In Australia a 'diner' is an American inspired/themed restaurant!

Comment: @Mazura: We don't have *diners* in the UK. Our *cafes* can be anything from a [greasy spoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasy_spoon) to a swanky [coffee house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffeehouse). That's not "regional variation", btw. Practically all Brits are aware of the breadth of possible referents, and most are quite happy to *use* the word flexibly, as well as *understand* the relevant meaning in context.

Comment: In the US, I've seen *cafe* used for shops that sell only coffee, restaurants that sell coffee and light meals, restaurants that serve ordinary full meals, expensive restaurants that serve gourmet meals, and bars that serve alcohol but no coffee at all.  At this point it basically means "some sort of food or drink is served here".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course the *Café Royal* in Regent Street, off Piccadilly, is something else! (Was it Peter Cook, or was it Steptoe who pronounced it "the Kaff Royal"?)

Answer (score 18):

Basically, a *café* is (in the US) a place you go for coffee and other beverages and maybe a light meal, such as a [sweet roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_roll) or perhaps some pie.  However, many cafés will also offer a sort of lunch menu with sandwiches and possibly burgers, fries, etc.

A *diner* is a place with offers full meals, generally of a relative proletarian nature (versus what would be served in a high-falutin' *restaurant*).  Typically burgers, fries, modest steaks, maybe some fish, a limited selection of salads, and, of course, an assortment of beverages, centered around coffee and soft drinks.

The *diner* would typically have [waiting staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiting_staff), while the *café* might be either a server or (stand up) counter service. But either might (or might not) have a sit-down counter, in addition to tables. Typically the *café* is open for breakfast and lunch only, while the *diner* is open for lunch and dinner, and maybe open for breakfast, maybe not.

A *fast food place* would have fare similar to a limited diner, only no waitstaff.

(In fairness--not that New Jersey deserves it--there is a lot of variability across the US as to what these terms mean.  My description above is probably most fitting to rural establishments, while metropolitan areas will develop their own quirks as to meaning.)

Comment: Diners that aren't open for breakfast? You must not live in New Jersey (where the diner is the state restaurant :-) ) A New Jersey diner without an extensive breakfast section in the menu, some of which is available all day, is unthinkable.

Comment: @PeterShor - I lived in New Jersey for two years, so I can say this with some authority:  New Jersey is weird.

Comment: I lived in New Jersey eight times longer than you did. And I won't disagree.

Comment: I would say another potentially big difference might be in the likelihood of offering outdoor seating. Cafe? Quite possibly. Diner? Never!

Comment: In New York, diners have waiters. Cafes are open for dinner too. Also, I would not call typical American food such as burgers and fries "proletarian". That's the thing about the US, even the rich and super rich eat burgers....many diners serving dinner have things like: meatloaf and pureed potatoes; broiled chicken of some sort and a vegetable or pork chops. "home-cooked" type of food.

Comment: @Lambie - I have never ever seen "pureed potatoes" on a menu anywhere in the US.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yeah, yeah, yeah, MASHED potatoes. The word just didn't come to mind

Answer (score 6):

To make it as simple as possible: they are quite similar, but with a different focus.

The connotations are going to vary from region to region and person to person, so adding a great deal of detail is kind of pointless. Here's the general gist, which would be accurate everywhere I've ever been in the US:

You go to a cafe for coffee, and might get some food while you're there.

You go to a diner to eat a meal (*dine*), which will probably involve a beverage, which could be coffee.

Comment: @curiousdannii I could, but I do cover all that in my profile.

Comment: @curiousdannii The point of this answer was to make things simple, as compared to the overly detailed other answers (one of which seems basically correct). What I've added is all I'm going to add. Also, I respectfully disagree about the profile. Adding where your experience comes from to *every single answer* clutters the answers. Put it in your profile where anybody can see it whenever they like. Much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, a diner has three characteristics features: a window counter through which you see the cook/kitchen, booths and a counter with stools. That is the classic American diner. Funnily enough, in cities like New York, they are today almost all owned by Greeks or descendants of Greeks. They have traditional American breakfast, lunch and dinner foods. Nothing too fancy. Caters to all income types and is typically not expensive. Traditionally, also diners were modelled on dining cars from trains.
Here is a "typical" diner, in Minnesota: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey%27s_Diner
The traditional ones (from the thirties) were often art deco.

A cafe is associated with the idea of little tables (sometimes placed outdoors) where you can partake of slightly fancier fare or "cuisine" (salads and omelettes and dishes cooked by a chef) and is more European (French, Italian etc) in feeling. Often, they also serve wine and beer. They are rather informal but the good is usually good. Layout and atmosphere is more sophisticated, usually, than a diner. You don't get truck drivers, for example, sipping white wine of a summer afternoon.
Here is one in Washington, DC
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HK_TST_1881_mall_restaurant_DG_Cafe_outdoor_sidewalk_umbrella.JPG

Food-wise, a cafe is more "sophisticated" than a diner. Diners are associated with typical American breakfasts, sandwiches for lunch and things like meatloaf for dinner. There is, of course, overlap.

I don't know why that Saskatoon Park Café and Diner has both words. Most likely, they want to appeal to both the cafe crowd and the diner crowd. They have pretty fancy sandwiches that go beyond typical diner fare....

http://www.parkcafe.ca/menu

Comment: I think your view of diners and cafes is relatively narrow.  I seriously doubt that the [Chatterbox Cafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Wobegon#Businesses.2C_organizations_and_landmarks) has anything that one would call "European cuisine" (unless you include lutefisk and lefse).

Comment: And Mickey's Diner is in Minnesota, not Michigan.  I've eaten there at least once and have driven by many times.

Comment: Fourth - and essential! - _characteristic_ feature of a _diner_: The jukebox!  Preferably with a [station at each booth](https://www.google.com/search?q=tabletop+jukebox&safe=off&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP7qbb56XNAhUeEFIKHfavBlcQsAQISg&biw=1543&bih=752)!

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know what European Cuisine could be, if not lutefisk and lefse. Those are both Scandanavian, as I'm sure you know! It is a pretty specific (too specific?) definition though, you're right.

Comment: @Dan - Actually, I'm told that Scandinavians detest lutefisk.

Comment: @HotLicks They may hate it, and I don't blame them, but it is a traditional Nordic food. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutefisk I was going off my family members' wisdom till now, but Wikipedia confirms it.

Comment: @Dan - I (with not a drop of Scandinavian blood in me) actually like lutefisk (in moderation), but my wife (full-blooded Norwegian) can't tolerate it.  Her Norwegian relatives laugh when told it's regarded as "traditional" in the US.

Comment: @Chatterbox Cafe my view of diners (in the US) and cafes (Europe, Latin American and the US) is very broad. Cafés in large US cities like Miami, NY etc. serve very sophisticated food, often, cooked by chefs. Those Scandavian foods you mention are not really "cuisine". They are regional foods..

Comment: @Dan While "European cuisine" doesn't have a precise definition, I think most people expect it to mean something like "food that's typical of Europe in general or, at least, large areas of Europe." Lutefisk is very much a regional thing and it would be very-hard-to-impossible to find it in most of Europe.

Comment: HotLicks I would agree with you, but then we'd both be wrong. :P

DavidRicherby I guess that's fair. Europe is a fairly diverese and quite expansive continent though, so I would think that there are a lot of things that should be considered European without being prolific across the continent.

Comment: Diners today do not have jukeboxes, necessarily.

Comment: @Lambie - then those are [not true scotsmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman), I mean, diners.

Comment: Yes, they are. None of you;lives in the country of diners, right?